# thunderbird web links won't open in existing chrome browser window

Tags: google-chrome, browser, thunderbird

When I click on a link in Thunderbird, it opens a new Chrome browser window, rather than opening a tab in an existing Chrome window.

This has only happened in the last few days.  Can't think of any related changes that have been made.

How do I revert back to opening in a tab in an existing Chrome window?

Thanks,

Steve.

Comment: have you changed chrome to the default

Comment: What os / are you up to date on the software?

Comment: Yes, Chrome is the default, and it was downloaded and installed only a month ago.  UPDATE: since yesterday, Thunderbird web links have been opening in the existing window of Chrome in a new tab.  I haven't changed anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symptoms resolved themselves without me changing anything.